# Getting SharePoint 2010 workflows running on SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, pnp-powershell, list-workflow

I am trying to get the SharePoint 2010 workflows running on the SharePoint list directly from the list name and not entering the list item.

But PnP PowerShell syntax needs me to enter the List item as well. Can you please help me with how can I modify the below script so that I don't need to enter the list items and could directly get the result from the list name:

```
$SiteURL="Enter URL"
$List="Enter List Name"
$ListItem="I don't have to use this in my script"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get Credentials)
Get-PnPWorkflowInstance -List $List -ListItem $ListItem

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: If you don't mind using C# instead of powershell, you can check out this link: https://bit.ly/2ZO1Mud Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the SPCoder tool.

Comment: I am working on a client's machine and the URL is blocked...is there anyway I could modify my powershell script to get the output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use csom to get the SharePoint 2010 workflows, below is my sample:

```
$webUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael"

$listName = "TestList"
$UserName="michael"
$Password ="password"
  
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))


$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $webUrl
$context.Credentials = $Credentials

$web = $context.Web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)

$WorkflowAssociations =$list.WorkflowAssociations;
$context.load($WorkflowAssociations)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$WorkflowAssociations

}
```

Comment: Getting error while executing above script

Comment: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" arguments:"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Comment: I tried adding.      Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"

 

     But error still occurs

Comment: Please try to run the script in SharePoint Online Management Shell: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588